# Error : Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';' What's wrong?

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

//Place your instance variables here
let questions = Questionbank()

@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var progressBar: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var progressLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let firstQuestion = questions.list[0]
    questionLabel.text = firstQuestion.questionText

}


@IBAction func answerPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

}


func updateUI() {

}


func nextQuestion() {

}


func checkAnswer() {

}


func startOver() {

}



}
```

This is my code above. And following is the error come up.

[image: Error message]

This is the errors come up.
There seems to be problem with questionLabel.text line but 
I can't figure it out. This is a part of ios tutorial I am currently
working on. 
Thank you for help.

Comment: There's some weird character inside `questionLabel` on the `questionLabel.text = firstQuestion.questionText` line. Delete that and type it again.

Comment: How do you know? To me I don't see any weird character on that line?

Comment: You can tell that it has some sort of non-visible character in the middle of it because of the way stack overflow is syntax highlighting it.

Comment: @SeanKlaus I know because I copy and pasted your code into a playground I see an error about a non-printable character. You can't see it because it's not printable.

Comment: Ok then I never typed anything werid character into the editor so why is it there?

Answer (score -1):

I just found out why.
Problem was questionLabel.text not being written using xcode auto complete feature.
First time I typed manually and got error.
Second time, I let Xcode autocomplete it and it worked.
Anyone know why this works this way?